# Should if statements be surrounded by blank lines to follow PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

I've read [the blank line section in pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). It says that we should surround top level functions with blank lines, but it doesn't say anything about if statements.

I've done some digging on what a top level is in Python and it seems to be anything that's not indented. Does this mean that if statements should be surrounded by blank lines? Are if statements considered functions?

I can't find anything on stack overflow about this.

Comment: Typically the standard dictates two blanklines pre and post a top level function's declaration; however if statements are not functions therefore you can follow any guideline as you please with that as long as it looks readable to you and- of course- follows PEP8 whilst followng your guidelines (IIRC PEP8 doesn't require much in regards to positioning relative to other code with if's)

Comment: No, `if` statements are not functions. It can make the code more readable to follow an `if...elif...else` section with a blank line, and maybe one before it, if you like. But beware of putting too many blank lines into a function, or the function will lose visual integrity and stop looking like a single unit.

Comment: Bear in mind that PEP-8 is a _guide_, you aren't obliged to strictly adhere to it unless you're writing Python code for the standard library. It's become the semi-official guide for the rest of us, though, so it makes sense to follow its recommendations when practical, especially if you want other people to read your code. ;)

Comment: A top level function is a function definition beginning with `def functioname`

Comment: Pep8 says: "Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines." An if statement is neither a function nor class definition. What you're looking for is also in that section: "Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections." As an if statement is a logical section, blank lines may be used sparingly to indicate it as such.

Comment: *"Are if statements considered functions?"* No, `if` statements and function definitions are two different kinds of [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"""
my cool and interesting program!
"""

import this_module
import that_module
import another_module


def procedure_to_do_this(*args):
    if args:
        print("the caller says %s!" % args[0])
    elif not args:
        print("the caller is too shy to say anything ;c")
    else:
        print("if you've reached this point, there's no turning back")

    return something


procedure_to_do_this()
```

Is how you'd typically form an if/elif/else structure, however at most times it is subjective to you whether that structure complies with the rest of the code or not, of course you can change it around if you feel there's too much code inside one of the conditional clauses and that you want to distinguish the conditionals, you can put an extra newline after the end of one conditional e.g.:

```
if this:
    <a lot of code>
    <a lot of nice code>
    <a lot of long code>
<newline>
elif that:
    <a lot of other code>
```

et cetera.

Always keep in mind that PEP8 is simple a styling guide[line], it by no means is to dictate the over-all design of your code because it is subjective itself to what people thought good styling looked when there was good or specific code there.

Not all code looks good in a certain style, so that's why it's a guideline and not something that Python strictly enforces and has implemented into the intepreter.